# Why is a projective module called "projective"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, projective-module, map-projections

Is it related to projections as in $P P = P$?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284039/origin-of-the-terminology-projective-module).

Comment: Thanks a lot, duplicate I guess.

Comment: "Objection your Honor, calling for speculation." There may be *believable* explanations, but in almost all cases one can't know for sure. Why are "modules" called modules in the first place? Or rings? Why are the natural numbers called "natural"? Note also that these questions are not of a mathematical nature; they make more sense in linguistics. There is no mathematical content in the choice of words for concepts, as long as the words are clearly defined and are used according to their definitions.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about.  Please use equations only.